# Dynamic Pivot table columns mysql

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I have following tables

**demographic_categories**

```
demographic_id  demographic_name
1               color
2               age_group
```

**project_tests**

```
test_id  group_id  project_id
1        1         1
2        1         1
```

**test_demographic_requirements**

```
test_id  project_id  demgraphic_id  demographic_value
1        1           1              blue
1        1           2              young
2        1           1              green
2        1           2              middle
```

And I need a query which would give me following result :

```
test_id  group_id  color  age_group 
1        1         blue   young
2        1         green  middle
```

I guess we need to use concept of pivot table to get the result, but I am unable to. And I demographic categories can we might be same they tend to change so I need something dynamic so what would be the best way to do it ?

I have tried doing the following based of previous similar questions but it doesn't seems to work for me, here is what I have tried:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
          'max(case when dc.demographic_name = ''',
          demographic_name,
          ''' then trd.demographic_value end) AS ',
          replace(demographic_name, ' ', '')
        )
      ) INTO @sql
    from demographic_categories;

    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT pt.test_id, pt.group_id,
    ', @sql,'
    from test_requirement_demographic trd
    LEFT JOIN demographic_categories dc ON trd.demographic_id = dc.demographic_id
    LEFT JOIN project_tests pt ON pt.test_id = trd.test_id and project_id =1
    group by pt.test_id;');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;

    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: But why are you so determined to do this in the RDBMS?

Comment: See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot for dynamic code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dynamic SQL is just fine except for one thing. It has an ambiguous column `project_id` on your second left join, Just replace it with `pt.project_id` or `trd.project_id` and it will give desired result.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
          'max(case when dc.demographic_name = ''',
          demographic_name,
          ''' then trd.demographic_value end) AS ',
          replace(demographic_name, ' ', '')
        )
      ) INTO @sql
    from demographic_categories;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT pt.test_id, pt.group_id,
', @sql,'
from test_demographic_requirements trd
LEFT JOIN demographic_categories dc ON trd.demographic_id = dc.demographic_id
LEFT JOIN project_tests pt ON pt.test_id = trd.test_id and pt.project_id =1
group by pt.test_id;');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I ran it on a rextester. Here is the link : [dynamic_pivot_test](http://rextester.com/JLELJ21093)

Comment: i tried in my workbench and it shows up this error : 09:35:58 PREPARE stmt FROM @sql Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1 0.000 sec

Comment: Is query you posted in your question running successfully?