# How to transform unique column values as column heads in mysql?

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I am working on a table in a MySQL database which has 3 columns which are following,

```
event_name campaign_name customer_id
event_1    campaign_1    1
event_2    campaign_1    1
event_1    campaign_1    1
event_2    campaign_1    1
event_2    campaign_1    2
```

I want to query unique and total count of customer_id for each combination of event_name and campaign_name in the following format,

```
campaign_name    event_1_unique_count   event_1_total_count  event_2_unique_count   event_2_total_count
campaign_1       1                     2                   2                        2
```

Number of event names can be different that's why i am looking for a generic solution.
Thanks.

Comment: This is basically a pivot table. Have a look at this SO question and its most upvoted answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql    another way, which I sometimes perform for the sake of speed, is export the resultset in Excel (or similar) and do the pivot there.

Comment: Search for dynamic pivot, you'll find plenty of questions / answers eg [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50596213/dynamic-pivot-table-columns-mysql)

Comment: thanks @Bjoern for guiding me towards pivot concept in mysql.